# Antivirus for Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, anti-virus

Just looking for a bit of advice on what AV product to use for SP2010 Foundy now that MS have binned Forefront...

I know McAfee do one and we're getting quotes for that but can anyone recommend any others?

Specifically one that would work with the original build of SP2010 (the farm has never been patched because it runs a load of custom code and they didn't want to risk patching) would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are so many anti virus software's for SharePoint. here is the lists

- AvePoint DocAve Antivirus
- TrendMicro PortalProtect
- BitDefender
- Symantec Protection
- McAfee Security
- Sophos Antivirus Protection
- Kapersky Security

Please check the below link to get  the details regarding the anti virus software's for SharePoint. 
[Antivirus and SharePoint](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2013/02/22/Antivirus-and-SharePoint-2013.aspx)

**Update**: Here is an another Excellent Article [Antivirus for SharePoint 2013](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2015/02/03/antivirus-sharepoint-2013/)

Here are the few points from the [Antivirus for SharePoint 2013](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2015/02/03/antivirus-sharepoint-2013/)   link

**Symantec Protection for SharePoint Servers**

http://www.symantec.com/protection-for-sharepoint-servers/

Familiar vendor to a lot of environments
Can be used with Symantec Enterprise Vault for SharePoint and Symantec Backup Exec for SharePoint to deliver a comprehensive security, archiving, and data recovery solution.

**ESET® Security for Microsoft SharePoint Server**

http://www.eset.com/int/business/products/collaboration-sharepoint/

First engine for SharePoint 2013 – very customisable / powerful.
Very light and efficient antivirus

**Kaspersky Security for Collaboration (SharePoint)**

Light and well known vendor, well trusted security solution

Hope it helps

Comment: That's awesome, cheers!